# I was trying to implement round robin assignment of leads to the members-users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, round-robin

I was trying to implement round robin assignment of leads to the members-users.
But when ever my function is called user cycle starts again, and all the leads are assigned to the first user. How can I assign next leads to the user that was next to the previously assigned user.
eg;
if lead1 is assigned to U2 and claimed, then next lead2 assignment should continue from U3.

Code that I used:
Rough:

```rb
def round_robin(selected_lead)
  lead = selected_lead
  users = %i(U1 U2 U3).cycle
  while lead.status !=“Claimed” do
    assigned_user=users.next
    # assigned_user <= Assign lead to
    # Check to wait 10 min for claimed response...
  end
  puts “Lead #{lead} has been assigned to #{assigned_user} 
end
```

I was doing this in ruby language.
any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `users` array doesn't preserve its state between the calls to `round_robin` (it is local for the method, so it gets discarded after the method call). As the result, on each call you assign to the result of `%i(U1 U2 U3).cycle.next`, which is obviously always the 1st element... You need to keep the iterator state between the calls to `round_robin` (so it must **not** be a local variable)

Comment: Maybe also consider just grabbing a random one (`%i(U1 U2 U3).sample`), it won't cycle through them in order, but will result in a random sample across your array element without having to maintain any state.

Comment: if U1 has a lead assigned and claimed. U2 has a lead assigned and not claimed. Who is the next lead assigned to?

Comment: @LesNightingill if U2 has lead assigned and not claimed then lead should be assigned to the next user U3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the concept of the next-user-to-be assigned a lead. I suggest doing this in a boolean column in the users table `next`. Only one user will ever have this attribute set to true, all others have it set to nil or false.

So in the User model, `User.next` is the next user that will receive a lead assignment

```rb
# in user.rb
  has_many :leads

  def self.next
    find_by(next: true) || first
  end
```

and `User.next_next` is the User *after* `User.next` where the order is simply the value of the id. (Can't just add 1 to the id, b/c there may be missing ids, due to deleted users)

```rb
# in user.rb

  def self.next_next
    # get the list of all User ids, and find the index of the one that has next=true
    next_index = ids.index(next.id)

    # find the index in the list of ids of the User after next, modulo User.count. 
    # So when you get to the last user, "round-robin" back to the first
    next_next_index = next_index.succ % count

    # return the User after next
    find(ids[next_next_index])
  end
```

When a lead is assigned, it is assigned to `User.next`, the value of that user's `next` attribute is set to false, and the value of the user after `User.next` has the value of the `next` attribute set to true

```rb
# in lead.rb
  belongs_to :user

  def assign_to_next_user
    User.assign_lead(self)
  end

# in user.rb

  def self.assign_lead(lead)
    next.leads << self
    next.update(next: false)
    next_next.update(next: true)
  end
```